# QtConcurrent in PySide/PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtconcurrent

I'm trying to figure out if subclassing [QtConcurrent](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QtConcurrent.html) and writing a run method inside it will work:

```
class Task(QtCore.QtConcurrent):

     def run(self, function):
           function()
```

Or is it completely useless?

Comment: Why won't you give it a try?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's completely useless, because [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html) is a namespace, not a class.

Also, neither PyQt nor PySide provide any of the functionality provided by `QtConcurrent`, because it's all template-based and therefore impossible to wrap.

PS: the PySide documentation you linked to is for the [ReduceOption](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html#ReduceOption-enum) enum. Since it's doubtful whether that enum has any use outside the `QtConcurrent` namespace, it's probably a bug that PySide includes it.

Comment: Very interesting. I was just about to experiment a little bit with `QtConcurrent` in PyQt5 when I realized that I can't find anything. Thanks for the hint. I guess C++ it is. :D

Comment: Might it be possible for someone to rewrite all this QtConcurrent in Python? I assume it wouldn't be very easy, but might it be possible? It seems frustrating that we have Futures in Python's concurrent.futures but PyQt5 is stuck in the Dark Ages.

Comment: @mikerodent [Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B)) are a C++ feature, which means `QtConcurrent` cannot be implemented in any meaningful sense in Python. You might be able to come up with some alternative API that reproduced *some* of the functionality, but it wouldn't really be `QtConcurrent` any more (e.g. [qconcurrent.py](https://gist.github.com/ales-erjavec/5ef43c5b3907a9e4924eec09bfb9d9c6)). I doubt whether it would ever be worth anyone's time trying to reproduce *all of it*, though (certainly the author of PyQt has never shown any interest in doing so when asked).

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck on the same problem in PyQt5.  I guess the only solution is to do this locally:

```
def connect(self):
    class ConnectThread(QThread):
        def __init__(self, func):
            super().__init__()
            self.func = func
        def run(self):
            self.func()
    self.connectThread = ConnectThread(self._connect)
    self.connectThread.start()

def _connect(self):
    if self._driver is None:
        uri = self.uriString()
        if uri and self.user and self.password:
            self.statusMessage.emit("Connecting to the Graph Database....", -1, "color:blue;")
            try:
                self._driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(self.user, self.password))
                self.statusMessage.emit("Connected!", 5000, "color:green;")
            except Exception as e:
                self.clearStatusMessage.emit()
                Error(str(e)).exec_()
                if __debug__:
                    raise e
```

And remember to set the thread to a member variable: `self.thread = ...` or else your thread reference will go out of scope, and most likely the thread object deleted.

You could also move your function-to-call into a local definition of it as Python allows both nested functions and classes within one another!

Answer (score -1):

The class you are looking for is [QRunnable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html).

Comment: That does not provide the ability to call any function I don't think...  Only option here is to inherit from QThread.  See my solution above.